# GCP - issues with connecting Vertex.AI to shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

We are trying to create training job in Vertex.AI and we need to connect with resources in our shared VPC. Project in which we are creating this job is service project. We have VPC with private services access configured already. (as described in https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/vpc-peering)

When we are trying to create a job and use this host network, we get a very generic error message:

```
Unable to start training due to the following error: Internal error encountered.
```

Everything seems alright and peering connection with private services (`servicenetworking`) is in an active state.

Does anyone maybe have an idea where can we look for more information about this problem or maybe some guides or pointers that could help us?

Answer (score 1):

A few points should be verified in this particular setup:

1. The Compute Engine and Service Networking APIs should be enabled for host and service projects, and the Vertex AI API should be enabled for the service project.
2. The VPC peering connection within your VPC and Google Services should be created in the host project.
3. You must specify the name of the network that you want Vertex AI to have access to (shared VPC), as stated in the following document [1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-private-ip#reserving-ip-ranges).
4. Verify that the service/user account used has the proper role (Compute Network user).